# Filter the data using jquery in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to filter the data available in HTML page.

Suppose there are three brands available in the page: "abc", "pqrs", "xyz" and brandNameSelected="abc". Now to filter the data on the page i am using this code snip.

```
$(".product-container").filter(function () {
    alert($(this).data('brand'));
    return $(this).data("brand").indexOf(brandNameSelected) > -1;
}).each(function (index, item) {
    alert("here");
    $(item).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

`alert($(this).data('brand'));` printing all the brands available. but i am not reaching to `alert("here");`

Can please some one help to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: That means none of the elements match the condition in the filter, and the collection is empty so `each` never runs.

Comment: alert($(this).data('brand')); printing abc for couple of items. so condition should match ideally.

Comment: can you explain what is that data object?

Comment: What type is `$(this).data('brand')`?

Comment: You'll have to show us *exactly* what `.data('brand')` and `brandNameSelected` returns, and use the console, alert is not a debugging tool.

Comment: `<li class='product-container'  data-category='$data[4]' data-brand='$data[3]' style='height:230px; width:150px;'>`

Comment: @adeneo `.data('brand')` returns all the brands available in page one by one and `brandNameSelected` is set to the brand for which i want to filter the data.

Comment: That doesn't really help much, you have to log the two values to the console and then you'll be able to figure out why there's no match. If there was a match, the alert would fire for each match.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/1488/ works

So the reason it is failing is because the value of `brandNameSelected` doesn't match the value obtained by `$(this).data('brand')`

```
brandNameSelected = "abc"

$(".product-container").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("brand").indexOf(brandNameSelected) > -1;
}).each(function (index, item) {
    $(item).css("background-color", "red");
});
```